# ZF2 custom routing

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am trying to setup routing for our ZF2 application.

We have URLS like this:

```
/foo/bar.json            >>> should call /Controller/Foo/BarController.php
/foo/bar/123.json        >>> should call /Controller/Foo/BarController.php
/foo/baz/bar.json        >>> should call /Controller/FooController.php
```

and the underlaying controller structure

```
/Controller/Foo/BarController.php
/Controller/FooController.php
```

It should route by looking up in the directory structure. So `/foo/baz/bar.json` should look 
if `/Controller/Foo/Baz/BarController.php` exists. If not, look if `/Controller/Foo/BazController.php` exists, else look for `/Controller/FooController.php` and else give a 404

However i do not seem to get mutch useful information from the zend documentation. I looked at the existing routers but it does not seem to me that any of these match the required functionality.

Also there does not seem to be any information in the zend docs about creating a custom router.

I tried to extend the Literal router and create one of my own by overriding the `match()` function and returning the `RouteMatch` object if a match was found, but it still gives me a 404 with a notice that thee was no matched route.

The module.config file was ofcourse also edited to add the new router. and added it to the invokables

Can anyone tell me some starters about how to write a custom router or does anyone know any good information about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it is the best way.

You can point all your URLS to one controller e.g. /Controller/RouteController.php. And there you can traverse  the url and dispath the appropriate controller:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $event = $this->getEvent();
    $routeMatch = $event->getRouteMatch();

    $locator = $this->getServiceLocator();
    if ($locator->has('ControllerLoader')) {
        $locator = $locator->get('ControllerLoader');
    }

    $url = parse_url($this->getRequest()->getUri());
    $path = str_replace('.json', '', $url['path']);
    $path = explode('/', trim($path, '/'));

    while (sizeof($path)){
        $controllerName = 'Controller\\' .implode('\\', $path);
        if ($locator->has($controllerName)) {
            return $this->forward()->dispatch($controllerName, $routeMatch->getParams());
        }

        array_pop($path);
    }

    //not found
}
```

Be sure to define your controllers in module config:

```
array(
  'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Controller\Foo\Baz' => 'Controller\Foo\BazController',
        ...
    )
  ),
);
```

Comment: I had already made this construction, but I wanted to get rid of a controller playing to be a router. ;)

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't think you mean directly looking up the directory structure, are you? You should never be doing that. If you've configured your application properly, you won't need it since zf2 handles the autoloading for you.

Anyway, there are a few ways to achieve this.

- Indeed create your customized Route class
- Match anything that start with /foo and route it to f.e. FooDispatchController in which you further analyze the `RouteMatch` object and `forward()` to the proper controller from there.

Comment: but then how do i create the custom router?